# Run integration tests on gitlab after merge only

Tags: gitlab, integration-testing

Assume I have a testing set of 99% tests that are fast (run in 2 min total) and 1% of integration tests with a run time of 20 min.

Does GitLab offer any way to run the fast tests in the pipeline before merge to master, and slow ones only after the merge has been done?

The idea here is that revert every couple of months is worth the benefit of a faster merge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can limit a GitLab job based on the branch name. If you separate the integration tests to their own job and limit it like this, they won't run when you push `some_feature_bracnh`, but will run if you merge that branch to `master`. E.g.:

```
stages:
  - dev
  - postmerge

unit-test:
  stage: dev
  scripts:
    - ./run_unit_tests.sh

integration-test
  stage: postmerge
  scripts:
    - ./run_integration_tests.sh
  only:
    refs:
    - master
```

Comment: I am not a Gitlab expert, so just to be clear: naming of stages does not matter(beside readability), only thing affecting behavior is the last 3 lines where you specify integration-test runs for master branch only?

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl The "stages" define the order of multi-job pipelines (and indeed, the names have no special meaning besides readability) - here, the "dev" stage will run first (containing one job) and then the "postmerge" stage (containing one job that runs only no master). You could omit the stages and have unit and integration tests run in parallel. With regard to running on master only - you are correct - the only thing controlling that is the "only" clause and the details under it.